# Give a char if a letter exists in a string

Tags: haskell

I'm currently having trouble doing a letterCheck function which gives me a string of numbers given two Strings. My code is below:

```
letterCheck :: String -> String -> String
letterCheck _ [] = []
letterCheck (w:ws) (y:ys)
 | w == y = '3' : letterCheck ws ys
 | w `elem` (y:ys) = '7' : letterCheck ws ys
 | otherwise = '9' : letterCheck ws ys
```

For reference the conditions I want are:

```
If letter in string 1 is the same as a letter in string 2, give '3';
If letter in string 1 exists in string 2 but is not the same, give '7';
Otherwise if a letter in string 1 isn't in string 2 at all, give '9';
```

The second guard in the code will not work because the second string being referenced decrements until no elements that exist in the full string are there for comparison. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your conditions don't look recursive and I would expect only one character as a result from it. You seem to want to apply the rule to all characters in the string but I'm not sure if string 1 / 2 stand for the input string or just the part right of the current first letters. In other words: what result do you expect of `letterCheck "ab" "ba"`? Should it be `"77"` or `"79"`?

Comment: I also don't understand your last sentence - could you give an example of an input and expected output where your program reports something different?

Comment: I apologize for lack of clarification, but letterCheck "ab" ba" SHOULD give me "77", though the code I have instead would give me "79".

Comment: Expected output should be as follows: letterCheck "ab" "ab" = "33", letterCheck "ab" "ba" = "77", letterCheck "ab" "cd" = "99"

Comment: The condition is incorrect because it does not check the entire string. In order to check the entire string, you need to be able to refer to the entire string somehow. A helper function that has access to the entire string and both truncated strings is in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want access to the whole string, you have to pass a copy of the whole string that doesn't get destructured. You can hide this implementation detail using a `where` block:

```
letterCheck ws ys = go ws ys ys where
    go _ [] _ = []
    go (w:ws) (y:ys) ysAll
        | w `elem` ysAll = '7' : letterCheck ws ys ysAll
```

Comment: Resolved using an implementation based off this. Thanks to everyone who reached out, I really appreciate it!